# How to post single document to Amazon CloudSearch with other than documents/batch endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I referred to the Amazon Cloudsearch documentation and found one endpoint (HTTP) which ends with "documents/batch". This endpoint is working fine.

Now my doubt is, is this the endpoint to use for both batch and single or is there any other endpoint for single document to upload. I have not found any other way to upload documents to Amazon Cloudsearch (single-by single) other than in batch.
Calling a batch is more costly.

Please share your views.

Comment: There is only the one endpoint. In what why do you think it is more costly?

Comment: The documentation says that calling batch more frequently will effect the cloud search performance. So is there any other endpoint to add a single document to cloud search through HTTP?

Comment: No, there is no other endpoint. The gist of the documentation you are referring to is that, if you have multiple documents to submit, submit them all in a single call rather than always submitting batches of size 1.

Comment: You can only send documents in batch to AWS CS. Either 1 or multiple documents, it's always a "batch". Instead of sending multiple calls with one or few docs, they recommend to group (up to 5 mb) and send in one call. Each 1,000 batch calls cost you $0.10, I think, so grouping also saves you some money.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a precise answer for this. by breaking your question into sections.

> **QUESTION 1** is this the endpoint to use for both batch and single or is there any
>   other endpoint for single document to upload?

There is only one endpoint provided by AWS Cloudsearch for Document uploads. I have attached here an image to show the 3 main values for any Cloudsearch domain.

1. Search Endpoint: to query
2. Document Endpoint: to upload
3. Domain ARN: resource name of the component

[image]

> **QUESTION 2** I have not found any other way to upload documents to cloud search
>   (single-by single) other than in batch

There is no other way to upload as a single document. Don't get confused about this endpoint. It is an endpoint for you to upload data in batches. But you can upload data in different batch sizes. This could be size 1 as well. (but please be mindful about the [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/limits.html))

> **QUESTION 3** Calling a batch is more costly?

AWS mentions this in their documentation. You are billed for the **total number of document batches** uploaded to your search domain. Uploaded documents are automatically indexed.

As you can see, the batch size is irrelevant to the pricing model. It's always better to upload a larger size in one batch (one call) - but keep in mind the limitations.

> $0.10 per 1,000 Batch Upload Requests (the maximum size for each batch
>   is 5 MB)

Read more about [Cloudsearch pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/pricing/).